# Nothing Shows up on scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I wanted to create a game in Xcode 7.2. I wanted to create a info screen which will have  some labels inside. But nothing shows up on the newly created scene. Whatever I put on the new scene, like images, sprites, labels. Nothing appears on the screen when I run it. But the code I wrote to create the label works perfectly fine in the "GameScene" which the game initially contains.

The code that I put in the InfoScene is the following:

```
import SpriteKit

class InfoScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  let thanksLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Arial")

  thanksLabel.text = "Thank you for Playing!"

  thanksLabel.fontSize = 45

  thanksLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

  self.addChild(thanksLabel)
}
```

}

Nothing seems wrong to me. If I put the above code in the GameScene which the template originally has, them the label will appear. Also, if I add a sprite on the scene, it doesn't show up as well. This really confuses me.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that instantiates and presents the `InfoScene`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've simply forgot to put your code to an instance method like:

**Swift 2.x**:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  // put your stuff here
}
```

**Swift 3.x:**

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView){
  // put your stuff here
}
```

`didMove` is called immediately after a scene is presented by a view. According to the actual documentation you might use this method to create the scene’s contents.

---

**Update**: (after your corrections and comment):

I think `InfoScene` is not launched for some reason.
Make sure your `InfoScene` is launched using breakpoints inside `didMoveToView` or simply add this line between your lines:

```
print("∙ \(type(of: self))")
```

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code... I actually used the didMoveToView method. But still nothing is in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using your `InfoScene` class?  How are you making this instance? Through an SKS file?  if so, you need to change the Custom class field to point to your `InfoScene`, by default it will go to `SKScene`